# Non-english Characters in cql filter in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, cql-filter

I have a shapefile loaded in GeoServer 2.8 and accessed by OpenLayers 2.13. This layer is in UTF-8 encoding and has some english and non-english records.
When i use english fields in cql-filter - as follows, but no differnce between WMS and WFS request- GeoServer filters data very well  and returns the result.

```
layer1 = new ol.layer.Image({
            title: 'Ostan',
            source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms',
                params: {
                    LAYERS: 'ws:layer1',
                    VERSION: '1.1.1',
                    CQL_FILTER: "NAME_ENG = 'sommy'"
                }
            })
        });
```

But if i try to use a field which contains non-english data in cql-filter, GeoServer returns no data. My webpage has following meta, as well:

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type" />
```

When i check geoserver log, i see some messy characters instead of my non-english string in cql-filter.

Comment: can you check what is actually set (in the network tab of your debugger)

Comment: Using Firebug, in Parameteres section, everything is correct. I see "CQL-Filter: Name = 'سامی' " which is right for arabic language. But in Geoserver log, i see some dummy characters instead of abovementioned arabic characters.

Comment: I used another shapefile with Win-1256 encoding and no help. Can anyone confirm that using characters other than ASCII is possible in CQL-Filter?

Comment: what happens if you URLEncode the request?

Comment: You mean using encodeURIComponent() for the query string?! If so, I've tried that. GeoServer gives a long trace for the error and says that "Could not parse CQL filter list. Lexical error at line 1, column 5.  Encountered: "%" " . If i don't use that, It sounds from log file that GeoServer runs the query but it misunderstoods the query stying. In this case, log file shows: "CQLFilter = [[ NAME = ?????±?§?? ]]"

Comment: Upgrading from Tomcat 7 to Tomcat 8 was the trick. Tomcat 8 uses UTF-8 as default encoding. Thanks to  Ben Caradoc-Davies and GeoServer mailing list.

Comment: please write an answer for the benefit of future searches - http://xkcd.com/979/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Answer is (All credit goes to to Ben Caradoc-Davies and GeoServer mailing list. Thanks them):
Adding  URIEncoding="UTF-8" or useBodyEncodingForURI ="true" to server.xml was the right solution for Tomcat 7.
Also, upgrading to Tomcat 8 solves everything without a need to add above codes.
According to this [link](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding), "In Tomcat 8 starting with 8.0.0 (8.0.0-RC3, to be specific), default value (strict compliance is off) of URIEncoding is now UTF-8."

Lesson to be learned: **As a end-user**, always use some recent versions but not exactly latest one. I had another experience of problem with Tomcat some time ago. After searching a lot, I understood that it is because of some new feature in Tomcat, and so, there is no document for problem available or a solution.